# Can't Connect to MongoDB from play app with salat: command failed [listDatabases]

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0, mlab, salat

I am trying to get started with the salat plugin in playframework. I have configured the database in `application.conf` and added all the dependencies to `Build.scala` and added salat to the `play.plugins` file. I haven't actually added any code to the project yet, I just followed the instructions on the github page, and then tried to run the project. I am getting the following error message

```
(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] play - mongodb [default] connected at heroku_app4620908@ds031907.mongolab.com:31907/heroku_app4620908
[error] application - 

! @6bchnaacn - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error [couldn't connect to [ds031907.mongolab.com/107.21.153.211:31907]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:71) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:258) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at se.radley.plugin.salat.SalatPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(SalatPlugin.scala:105) ~[play-plugins-salat_2.9.1-1.0.8.jar:1.0.8]
    at se.radley.plugin.salat.SalatPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(SalatPlugin.scala:98) ~[play-plugins-salat_2.9.1-1.0.8.jar:1.0.8]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command failed [listDatabases]: { "serverUsed" : "db-uri" , "errmsg" : "need to login" , "ok" : 0.0}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:88) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.8.0.jar:na
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:134) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getDatabaseNames(Mongo.java:356) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection.getDatabaseNames(MongoConnection.scala:190) ~[casbah-core_2.9.1-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at se.radley.plugin.salat.SalatPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(SalatPlugin.scala:103) ~[play-plugins-salat_2.9.1-1.0.8.jar:1.0.8]
    at se.radley.plugin.salat.SalatPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(SalatPlugin.scala:98) ~[play-plugins-salat_2.9.1-1.0.8.jar:1.0.8]
```

I am stumped because I added my password and everything to the conf file. From the log it looks as though whatever is trying to connect to the database for me, is not logging in first, using the info I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've the problem as well...

it should come with the SalatPlugin's onStart method that is requesting all database names: `source._2.connection.getDatabaseNames()`.

This code is just testing the aliveness of the server...

I'm gonna check with leon how we could this differently! Sadly, you won't be able to connect until this will be fixed!

Stay tuned on this issue https://github.com/leon/play-salat/issues/23

Comment: I would really like to pull the project down and try to fix this myself, but I am a bit mystified by sbt and how I can build from source. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021538/how-can-i-build-a-plugin-from-source-and-use-it-in-my-play-app

Comment: Is there a way I can configure the plugin from the global `onStart` method?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because the Global onStart method is post plugins' one... Which is logical. Furthermore this specific behavior won't be resolved using configuration :(

Answer (score 6):

As you say, it looks like the root issue is that MongoDB is rejecting the command "listDatabases". This command [requires administrator access](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/List+of+Database+Commands) to the MongoDB process since it reveals information about the other databases hosted there.

Unfortunately, the message it returns, "need to login", is a little misleading. You have logged in! You just don't have permission to list the databases.

Here's a simple experiment you can try yourself with the MongoDB shell. See that "show dbs" fails with the same error message you got in your app, but "show collections", which doesn't require access to any other databases outside your own, succeeds?

```
% mongo ds031907.mongolab.com:31907/heroku_app4620908 -u heroku_app4620908 -p your_password
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.7
connecting to: ds031907.mongolab.com:31907/heroku_app4620908
> show dbs
Fri Aug 17 13:12:10 uncaught exception: listDatabases failed:{ "errmsg" : "need to login", "ok" : 0 }
> show collections
system.indexes
system.users
```

*(Note: I did this with my own MongoLab account and modified the text when copying and pasting here so you could just copy it into your terminal.)*

Is there a way to avoid making the listDatabases call? I'm not familiar with the framework you're using.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought that must be the problem, I am working on trying to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the latest version of play-salat, it now uses getCollectionNames instead

Answer (score 0):

> use admin
>
> db.addUser('userName', 'userPassword')
>
> db.auth('userName', 'userPassword')
>
> show dbs

java:

DB db = mongo.getDB("YouDBName") ;

db.authenticate("userName", "userPassword".toCharArray()) ;

System.out.println(mongo.getDatabaseNames()) ;