# How can I build a plugin from source and use it in my play app

Tags: scala, maven, playframework-2.0, sbt, ivy

I have basically no knowledge of sbt and know very little about maven or ivy. There is a play plugin on github, that I would like to modify and use in my project. However I am struggling to figure out how I can pull it down from github and begin using it in my play project. I have tried various things involving using sbt commands. But sbt never behaves the way it is supposed to in the tutorials. Could anyone give me some simple steps to follow on how to go from Play Plugin on github -> utilizing plugin in play app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt source dependencies are, in my opinion, notoriously fickle. That being said, for a project dependency they're [not too hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git). The [sbt wiki page on plugins](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Plugins) specifically has a section, 1d, on source dependencies, so I'd recommend reading that.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know sbt can pull stuff from git. Usually I used `publish-local` in such cases.